# R join tables by variable with multiple year observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple tables all with the same variable names that I want to join by an ID, but each table represents another year. If I use an inner.join, it will correctly only keep those IDs in each table, but it will then create new variables for observations (i.e. X becomes X.x and X.y in the same row). I could use rbind, but that would keep all the data when I only want those that appear in each table.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = 1:3,
                  x2 = c(12,14,11),
                  year = 2020)
df2 <- data.frame(x1 = 2:4,
                  x2 = c(15,17,13),
                  year = 2021)
dfall <- inner_join(df1,df2,by="x1")
```

This results in:

```
 x1 x2.x year.x x2.y year.y
  2   14   2020   15   2021
  3   11   2020   17   2021
```

But I want this:

```
 x1   x2   year
  2   14   2020   
  2   15   2021
  3   11   2020
  3   17   2021
```

Is there a join where I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr::bind_rows` and then `filter` would work:

```
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
  filter(x1 %in% intersect(df1$x1, df2$x1))
```

You can pipe the output to `arrange(x1)` to sort the output if needed.

**Output**

```
  x1 x2 year
1  2 14 2020
2  3 11 2020
3  2 15 2021
4  3 17 2021
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
inner_join(df1,df2,by="x1") %>%
  pivot_longer(-x1, names_pattern="(.*)\\.(.*)",
               names_to=c(".value", "val")) %>%
  select(-val)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      x1    x2  year
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2    14  2020
# 2     2    15  2021
# 3     3    11  2020
# 4     3    17  2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's an inner join of your two approaches so far.

```
dfall <- inner_join(rbind(df1, df2) , inner_join(df1, df2 ,  by="x1") %>% select(x1))
```

Here's another option. It creates a column `n` which is equal to the number of times that each `x1` appears, and then filters only those which appear as many times as there distinct values for `year`. You could change `n==length(unique(year))` to `n>=2` if you wanted any records that appear in more than one year/table, as opposed to those which appear in every year/table. This one is nice because it is easy to scale up to a large number of input tables.

```
dfall <- rbind(df1, df2) %>% 
  add_count(x1) %>% 
  filter(n==length(unique(year))) %>% 
  select(-n)
```